# Reconnect to the internet automatically

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android chat application. On startup the application launches a service. The service connects to the chat server. If for some reason the connection goes down, the user can click a button and the reconnect() function gets called.

The application runs on a mobile device. The application connects to the Internet via Wi-Fi. If the user, walking with his phone, goes out of the Wi-Fi coverage area, the connection goes down. I want my application to automatically try to reconnect to the Internet in such cases. What's the best way to do this in your opinion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add to Manifest:

```
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">            </uses-permission>
...
    <receiver android:name=".Internet" android:enabled="true"> 
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter> 
    </receiver> 
...
```

Receiver:

```
    package YourPackage;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;

    public class Internet extends BroadcastReceiver
    {    
        @Override
        public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) 
        {   
            if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"))
            {
                if isInternet(context)
                { 
                    // Your Code
                }
            }       
        }

        public boolean isInternet(Context context) 
        {
            ConnectivityManager IM = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = IM.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            return activeNetworkInfo != null;
        }     
    }
```

Comment: Is the broadcast sent automatically by Android environment?

Comment: Yes. System will send broadcast when network state is change.

Comment: I don't see the code where the app try to reconnect if network is lost.